# How can I modify my for loop so that it extracts the correct data

Tags: python

```
thread_list = ['DWr','Idle','MulWr','Lock']
Target_list = ['0','0','0','1']
trd_coor = [26,10,51,10,226,10,251,10]
mem_coor = [10,215,35,215,60,215,85,215]
targ_1 = ['write','unchachable']
count_T = 0
count_X1 = 0
count_Y1 = 0
count_target = 0
count_target_1 = 0
count_dash_T = 0
T = []
trd_Y1 = []
count_dash_T_list = [0,1,2,3]
for i in trd_coor[1::2]:
    Y1 = i
    trd_Y1.append(Y1)
for i in range(0,len(count_dash_T_list)):
    target = Target_list[count_target]
    count_target += 1
    print(target)
    for i in targ_1:
        if (target == '0'):
            if (i == 'write'):
                X2 = mem_coor[0]
                Y2 = mem_coor[1]
        elif (target == '1'):
            if (i == 'uncachable'):
                X2 = mem_coor[2]
                Y2 = mem_coor[3]
            else:
                break
                    
    print(X2)
    print(Y2)
```

When the element in target_list is 1 I want the output to be 35,215 this is my current output:
0
10
215
0
10
215
0
10
215
1
10
215

and this is the output I want:
0
10
215
0
10
215
0
10
215
1
35
215

Comment: `'unchachable' != 'uncachable'`

Comment: Fixed this issue and I am getting the same output

Comment: Just use a debugger. You will see that when `i == 1`, no assignment of `X2` and `Y2` will happen and the old values will be printed. How exactly your code should behave and what the logic behind it is, is something only you can know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is two problems

1. - typo with word `unchachable`
2. - `else` statement with `break`

If you see closely then when we go into last `for`

```
 for i in targ_1:
        if (target == '0'):
            if (i == 'write'):
                X2 = mem_coor[0]
                Y2 = mem_coor[1]
        elif (target == '1'):
            if (i == 'uncachable'):
                X2 = mem_coor[2]
                Y2 = mem_coor[3]
            else:
                break
```

there `target` value is `1` so we go to `elif` and check `if` statemen. But `i`  is `write` so we go to `else` and then `break`.

If You change type and remove break, then it should work

```
thread_list = ['DWr','Idle','MulWr','Lock']
Target_list = ['0','0','0','1']
trd_coor = [26,10,51,10,226,10,251,10]
mem_coor = [10,215,35,215,60,215,85,215]
targ_1 = ['write','unchachable']
count_T = 0
count_X1 = 0
count_Y1 = 0
count_target = 0
count_target_1 = 0
count_dash_T = 0
T = []
trd_Y1 = []
count_dash_T_list = [0,1,2,3]

for i in trd_coor[1::2]:
    Y1 = i
    trd_Y1.append(Y1)
for i in range(0,len(count_dash_T_list)):
    target = Target_list[count_target]
    count_target += 1
    print(target)
    for i in targ_1:
        if (target == '0'):
            if (i == 'write'):
                X2 = mem_coor[0]
                Y2 = mem_coor[1]
        elif (target == '1'):
            if (i == 'unchachable'):
                X2 = mem_coor[2]
                Y2 = mem_coor[3]
    print(X2)
    print(Y2)
```